# Why isn't my "While Loop" computing and printing out a simple 3N+1 equation?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, system.out, date-arithmetic

So I had to write a simple code that would compute the 3N+1 equation; where N is an integer user types in and if it is a positive integer than N = N / 2 and if negative integer than N = N * 3 + 1.

However from what I can understand, my code doesn't work after the first while loop and hence prints nothing. What am I doing wrong? *New to programming and still learning so I appreciate your help :)*

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class ThreeNplusOneProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int N; Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); int counter; 

        System.out.println("Please Enter an integer: ");
        N = input.nextInt();

        while ( N <= 0 ) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Please Enter an integer greater than zero: ");
            N = input.nextInt();
        }

        //So far we know that N is great than Zero

        System.out.println(N);
        counter = 1;
        while ( N != 1 ) { 

            if (N == N % 2 )
                N = N / 2; 

            else N = N * 3 + 1; 

            counter = counter + 1; 

        }

        System.out.println("There were" + counter + "terms in the sequence");
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it works fine when applying @LeeNeverGup 's  advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is wrong: `if (N == N % 2 )`
N % 2 returns 1 or 0. You should use `if (0 == N % 2 )` to check for being odd / even.

Comment: I am not the question raiser, but I witness your answer is correct and  this is the only major problem of the given program.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `if (N == N % 2)`, you might just want to check `if (N >= 0)` since you do state that you are looking to check `if it is a positive integer`.